# How to switch between environments and run tests in SoapUi using Java?

Tags: soapui

Is there any way to switch between the environments in SoapUI pro from a script? I have to create a script that switches the environment 2 after the tests ran on environment 1. I am using the test runner to run my scripts from eclipse.
Please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can drill down and use Groovy rather than Java to change the environment like this:

```
log.info 'Current environment is ' + testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getActiveEnvironment().name

testRunner.testCase.project.setActiveEnvironment("Test")
log.info 'Environment afterwards is now ' + testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getActiveEnvironment().name

// Now run tests in the new environment.
def testCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("MyTestSuite").getTestCaseByName("MyTestCase")
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
testCase.run(properties, false)
```

Depending on how your test cases are structured, you may need to write a new test case that just includes the above as a Groovy test step and calls out to invoke your other test cases.